# how to handle recyclerview click listener to open new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-recyclerview

I want to open another fragment in onclick of recyclerview (One item). how to open another fragment on recyclerview click listener. I want to move to another fragment on recyler view one list to open another fragment. i have set recycler view and dapter too.

```
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ListCallback> listCallback = new ArrayList<>();

     public static SearchResultFragment newInstance() {
    return new SearchResultFragment();
}

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result, 
      container, false);

       recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new 
        RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) 
        {


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean 
        disallowIntercept) {

        }
        });
        return view;
        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to set your onItemClickListener for your adapter...

> https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

and then while passing listener to the constructor of your RecyclerView Adapter.. 
write this in onitemclick..

```
Fragment fragment = new XYZFragment();
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction..... and so on..
```

to replace your current fragment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write onClickListner inside adapter like below.

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }

        public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {

            name.setText(item.name);
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(item.imageUrl).into(image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                   // This is OnClick of any list Item
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }

            });
}
```

take an interface inside your adapter like below

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
    }
```

In your parent Activity implement above interface and write code to replace Fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();
```